# JavaFX comparing resultset for setting text to label using List<Label> show blank label

Tags: javafx

How do i setText to labelList using the if-else statement from a database. I try comparing the resultset from query to the labelList so i can set the text to the label with the matched label Id, but the iteration on labelList
shows...

> ```
> Label[id=labelts, styleClass=label]'' 
> Label[id=labeltt, styleClass=label]''  
> Label[id=labeltu, styleClass=label]'' 
> Label[id=labeltv, styleClass=label]''
> ```

This is the FXML file for the problem.

```
    FXML.fxml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

    <?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
    <?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
    <?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
    <?import java.util.ArrayList?>

    <AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.141" fx:controller="randomvar.FXMLDocumentController">
        <VBox layoutX="250.0" layoutY="83.0" spacing="5.0">
            <children>
                <Label fx:id="labelts" prefWidth="100.0" style="-fx-border-color: gray;" />
                <Label fx:id="labeltt" prefWidth="100.0" style="-fx-border-color: gray;" />
                <Label fx:id="labeltu" prefWidth="100.0" style="-fx-border-color: gray;" />
                <Label fx:id="labeltv" prefWidth="100.0" style="-fx-border-color: gray;" />

                <fx:define>
                    <ArrayList fx:id="labelList" >
                        <fx:reference source="labelts"/>
                        <fx:reference source="labeltt"/>
                        <fx:reference source="labeltu"/>
                        <fx:reference source="labeltv"/>
                    </ArrayList>
                </fx:define>          
            </children>
        </VBox>
    </AnchorPane>
```

This is the Controller file, how to get the script to show the label id "labelts" instead of showing "Label[id=labelts, styleClass=label]"

```
    FXMLDocumentController
    package randomvar;

    import java.sql.Connection;
    import java.sql.DriverManager;
    import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
    import java.sql.ResultSet;
    import java.sql.SQLException;
    import java.util.List;
    import javafx.fxml.FXML;
    import javafx.scene.control.Label;

    public class FXMLDocumentController {

        @FXML
        private List<Label> labelList;

        public void initialize() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {

            Connection conn = null;

            Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:C:\\test.db");

            String qry = "Select caller, Count(callout) as total from tbldata where caller = ?";

            PreparedStatement ps_qry = conn.prepareStatement(qry);
            ps_qry.setString(1, "ts");
            ResultSet rs_qry = ps_qry.executeQuery();
            while (rs_qry.next()) {

                String name_ = rs_qry.getString("caller");
                String total_ = String.valueOf(rs_qry.getInt("total"));

                for (int i = 0; i < labelList.size(); i++) {
                    System.out.println(labelList.get(i));                        
                    if (labelList.get(i).equals(name_)) {
                        labelList.get(i).setText(total_);
                    }
                }
            }
            rs_qry.close();
            ps_qry.close();
            conn.close();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This condition is always `false` because you work with different object types: `Label` and `String`:

```
if (labelList.get(i).equals(name_)) {
```

try this variant where you get an id:

```
if (labelList.get(i).getId().equals(name_)) {
```

To print only label id:

```
System.out.println(labelList.get(i).getId());
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank You Dmytro... I used your solution as below ....

```
    for (int i = 0; i < labelList.size(); i++) {

        if (labelList.get(i).getId().contains(name_)) {
            System.out.println(labelList.get(i).getId());
            labelList.get(i).setText(total_);
        }
```

Comment: Looks good, but using of `contains()` is risky a bit because for example for name `labelt` you will update the first found Label because `labelts` contains `labelt`. If you plan to have names exactly the same as label ids better to use `equals()`.

Comment: sorry for late reply.. will use equals() as you advised.